# SQL Server Weekdays function

Tags: t-sql

I'm using the following stored procedure to get an array of dates based on a weeknumber:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetweekdays] (
    @year INT,
    @weekno INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0)) AS Sunday, 
DATEADD(day, 2, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) as Monday,
DATEADD(day, 3, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) as Tuesday,
DATEADD(day, 4, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) as Wednesday,
DATEADD(day, 5, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) as Thursday,
DATEADD(day, 6, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) as Friday,
DATEADD(day, 7, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) as Saturday
```

And I'm calling it with....

```
DECLARE @WeekNo int= convert(int,DATEPART(week, getdate()));
DECLARE @Year int=convert(int, DATEPART(year, getdate()))

Select * from dbo.udfGetweekdays(@WeekNo,@year)
```

But the error says...

> Msg 517, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're passing the weeks to the year parameter, and the year to the weeks parameter. This means you want to add -1896 years to date `0` (`1900-01-01`), which would result in `0004-01-01`, which can't be represented in a `datetime`.

Comment: Just as a side note, you are also skipping a day.  When your query runs Sunday is 2023-01-15 and Monday is 2023-01-17.  Did you intentionally skip over the 16th?

Comment: Well spotted. Thanks!